# Unable to show profile in view ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Since i am new to asp.net mvc 
Getting this error
I want to show Profile to user in View 
"The name 'o' does not exist in the current context"

**View**

```
@model Test.Models.Customer 

          Name:  @o.CST_Name 
          Email:  @o.CST_Email 
          Gender:  @o.CST_Gender
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ViewProfileCustomer(string id)
        {
            var user = db.Customers.Single(u => u.CST_Username == id);

            return View(user);
        }
```

It shows this error [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYrMu.png)

Comment: What type is returned from `db.Customers`

Answer (score 1):

```
@model Test.Models.Customer 

      Name:  @Model.CST_Name 
      Email:  @Model.CST_Email 
      Gender:  @Model.CST_Gender
```

You always can access to the model that passed to view via `@Model`

Comment: Probably you are passing a null object to View because there is no Customer in your database with that Id

Comment: Sir I am logging in using the details... how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

That error shows up when View is trying to access property on NULL object, so 'no object' = 'no property'. Make sure that user object has some data in after Action call, but this code should display view content anyway.

Controller

```
public ActionResult ViewProfileCustomer(string id)
{
   var user = db.Customer.FirstOrDefault(u => u.CST_Username == id);

   return View(user);
}
```

View
@model Test.Models.Customer

```
  Name:  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CST_Name) 
  Email:  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model..CST_Email 
  Gender:  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model..CST_Gender)
```